# Doing Principal Components in SAS Using a Holdout and to Score New Data

Tags: sas, proc, enterprise-guide

I am performing Principal Components Analysis in SAS Enterprise Guide and wish to compute factor/component scores on some holdout.

KeepCombinedLR is my primary source of truth. I have another dataset, with the exact same variables, that I would like to be scored without including it in the actual factor analyses.

```
proc factor data = KeepCombinedLR
simple
method = prin
priors = one
rotate = varimax reorder
mineigen = 1
nfactors = 25
out = FactorScores;
var var1--var40;
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
data Fitness;
   input Age Weight Oxygen RunTime RestPulse RunPulse @@;
   datalines;
44 89.47  44.609 11.37 62 178     40 75.07  45.313 10.07 62 185
44 85.84  54.297  8.65 45 156     42 68.15  59.571  8.17 40 166
38 89.02  49.874  9.22 55 178     47 77.45  44.811 11.63 58 176
40 75.98  45.681 11.95 70 176     43 81.19  49.091 10.85 64 162
44 81.42  39.442 13.08 63 174     38 81.87  60.055  8.63 48 170
44 73.03  50.541 10.13 45 168     45 87.66  37.388 14.03 56 186
;
proc factor data=Fitness outstat=FactOut
            method=prin rotate=varimax score;
   var Age Weight RunTime RunPulse RestPulse;
   title 'Factor Scoring Example';
run;
proc print data=FactOut;
   title2 'Data Set from PROC FACTOR';
run;
proc score data=Fitness score=FactOut out=FScore;
   var Age Weight RunTime RunPulse RestPulse;
run;
proc print data=FScore;
   title2 'Data Set from PROC SCORE';
run;
```

PROC SCORE will score your data for you, using your 'holdout' data set.

https://documentation.sas.com/?docsetId=statug&docsetTarget=statug_score_examples01.htm&docsetVersion=14.3&locale=en